# Get value till 5 digits in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to run a SQL query and its output of a column should contain value till 5 decimals but it's by default rounding till 2 digits. I am using the below given query. Can someone please help me with this.

```
declare @VITG decimal(18,5)
select Left(wount(@VITG,18,5)) as VITG  
from DBFFile
```

Comment: Can you show some sample input and expected output and also tag the Version  of SQL you are using

Comment: Sample input is below 1737642.0000
4446788.0000
521713833.0000
928449592.0000
410557.0000
3453049475801.1200
447.0000
3453049886805.1200
2052441109764.2500
1161315098753.7200 I am trying to extract data from a .DBF file using this SQL statement

Answer (score 2):

```
select  CAST(MyNymber AS DECIMAL(18,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
select convert(decimal(18,5),ColumnName) as VITG  
from DBFFile
```

As your not using T-sql Datasourse you should do this is code for ex in c# you have to do some thing like this.

```
var columnValue=From_Query_Result_As_String;
if(columnValue.Substring(columnValue.IndexOf(".")+1).Length>=5)
{
      columnValue=Convert.ToDecimal(columnValue.Substring(0,columnValue.IndexOf(".")+6));
}
```

Comment: I got an error as "Undefined function 'convert' in expression"

Comment: VITG is my column name

Comment: @Anoop this function is T-SQL valid only for MS SQL.you should done this in code.

Comment: I am using it inside code but still it's not working for me!

Comment: @m.kudi . . . This is standard SQL and should work in just about any database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff for access .DBF file OledbConnection is used so OleDbCommand is used and this function is not valid for Oledb.

Comment: @m.kudi . . . You should ask *another* question and tag it as `ms-access`.  This question has multiple correct answers that you would invalidate by changing the tag at this point.  Invalid answers attract downvotes, so it is rude to change a question so existing answers attract downvotes.